# Copying files, renaming conflicts

Tags: file-system, powershell

I wrote a script to copy a file, but this file already exists in the target directory. So, first I need to rename the original file.

The script works, but a colleague did not want to use it because it is too complex. I would like to know how can I improve the code of this script. In some sense it seems to be overkill for simple task. I would like to find an objective reason to that opinion.

```
###GLOBAL VARIABLES

$goodDir = "..."
$targetDir = "..."
$goodFile = "..."
$targetFile = "..."

$app = "..."
$logDir= "..."
$timestamp = Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff" | foreach {$_ -replace ":", "."}

$log_name = $app + "_pscp-" + $timestamp + ".log"
$log_file = $logDir + $log_name



########################
#FUNCTIONS
########################



Function WriteLog
{
  param(

    [Int]$ecode=0,
    [string]$msg="Error Message"
  )
  $now = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"
  $messageToLog = $now + ":[exit code " + $ecode.ToString() + "] :`t" + $msg
  Add-Content $log_file -value $messageToLog
}

function rename-File {
    param(
        # file to copy
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$fname,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$from
        )
        $now = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        $toNewName = $fname + "-Copy-" + $now
        try {
            Rename-Item -Path $from$fname $toNewName -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {
            WriteLog -ecode 4 -msg "The item $_.Exception.ItemName failed with the following message $_.Exception.Message" 
            Break 
        }
        Finally {
            WriteLog -msg "Rename FILE $fName `r`n`t`t`t`t`t`tFROM $from `r`n`t`t`t`t`t`tTO $toNewName"
        }

    }



function copy-File {
    param(
        # file to copy
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$fname,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$from,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
        [string]$to    )

        try {
            Copy-Item -Path $from$fname -Destination $to -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        catch {
        WriteLog -ecode 4 -msg "The item $_.Exception.ItemName failed with the following message $_.Exception.Message" 
        Break}
        Finally {
        WriteLog -msg "Copy FILE $fName `r`n`t`t`t`t`t`tFROM $from `r`n`t`t`t`t`t`tTO $to"
    }

    }

### MAIN ###


rename-File -fname $targetFile -from $targetDir
copy-File -fname $goodFile -from $goodDir -to $targetDir$targetFile
```

Comment: `WriteLog -ecode 4 -msg "The item $_.Exception.ItemName..."` - complex enough that you didn't even run it enough to notice that it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some tipps:

- Try to avoid / minimize the amout of global variables.
- Use [approved verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see `Get-Verb`) for your functions (the first letter should be uppercase).
- Use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to combine a path.
- Use string interpolation

  ```
  "${app}_pscp-$timestamp.log"
  ```

  or the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx)

  ```
  '{0}_pscp-{1:dd-MMM-yyyy HH.mm.ss.fff}.log' -f $app, (Get-Date)
  ```

  instead of string concatenation.

Also, I would not create a `Copy-File` nor a `Rename-File` function. Just invoke `Copy-Item` and `Rename-Item` in the main…

Comment: I am new on this forum. I am not sure if say thank you is common. But I am very grateful with your comments Martin Brandl. Just one thing, if I want to rename and copy and do something else in each of those tasks, is it Ok to put them in a function? Or what could be a best practice for a powershel script?

Comment: I would clarify one of your points. He is not using global variables his functions should have access to the parent scope which is where those variable are located. Avoided globals is a good idea but these are not technically globals

Comment: @Matt I see your point. The only real global variable there is $log_file, it is used in the WriteLog function. I try to avoid using variables inside of a function when these variables are declared in the parent scope.  For me is clearer in that way.